# Excel. Change the colour of the comment indicator

Tags: microsoft-excel, comments

Is it possible to change the colour of the comment indicator in Excel ? (the little red triangle)

Red does not fit in well with the colour scheme of a dashboard I am working on ?

I know you can change the colour for an error indicator, or even turn it off completely with vba, see below. I was hoping there are some similar settings for comments ?

```
Sub OFF()
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it's not possible to do it natively.

The only solution (but it's very heavy) would be to use VBA, in order to add a small triangle to the cell if it has a comment. As a shape, it can be any color you want.

[This website](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2253-excel-change-comment-indicator-color.html) provides a VBA code to do it.

Comment: Ahhhh Damn, the answer I was dreading, Thanks Anyway

Comment: @PeterH: if this answers your question, please accept it

Comment: @MátéJuhász I will see if any other answers come along before accepting.

Comment: Also, check [this forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/80960-change-comment-indicator-color.html). They list some issues, like merged cells. Good to know!